# jQuery mobile add custom icon to list menu

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

How do I add an custom icon to the left listview. For each listview I have an icon that is different from one another. I tried using  tag to display icon but I get a bit of a problem. What should I add in the css so that it can be done?

```
<li><img src="css/test.png"><a href="epg.html" data-rel="page" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true">Menu 1</a></li>
```

The result is like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restructure you html a little bit but here's the official documentation on it.

[ListView Icons](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-16)

And foryour example:

`<li><a href="epg.html" data-rel="page" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true"><img src="css/test.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none">Menu 1</a></li>`

*Note:  This is supposed to be for a 16x16 icon.  Your icon may be a lttiel large.  Can't quite tell.